# Errors in std::make_shared() when trying to make shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, visual-c++-2010, make-shared

(Using Visual Studio 2010) I'm trying to create a shared_ptr of an existing class in my project (class was written a decade before std::shared_ptr existed). This class takes a non-const pointer to another object, it's empty parameter constructor is private.

```
class Foobar {
public:
    Foobar(Baz* rBaz);

private:
    Foobar();
}
```

When I try to create a shared_ptr to it, things don't go well:

```
Baz* myBaz = new Baz();
std::shared_ptr<Foobar> sharedFoo = std::make_shared<Foobar>(new Foobar(myBaz));
```

On VS2010, this gives me

```
error C2664: 'Foobar::Foobar(const Foobar &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Foobar *' to 'const Foobar &'
3>          Reason: cannot convert from 'Foobar *' to 'const Foobar'
```

For some reason it appears to be calling the copy constructor of `Foobar` instead of the constructor that takes a `Baz*`.

I'm also not sure about the `cannot convert from 'Foobar *' to 'const Foobar'` part. My best interpretation is that my templated-type of `shared_ptr<Foobar>` is wrong. I made it `shared_ptr<Foobar*>` but this seems wrong, all examples I've seen don't make the type a raw pointer.

It seems that making everything `shared_ptr<Foobar*>` compiles properly, but will that prevent the `Foobar` object from getting deleted properly when all `shared_ptr`'s go out of scope?

**Edit:** This seems related, but I'm not using Boost: [boost make_shared takes in a const reference. Any way to get around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373896/boost-make-shared-takes-in-a-const-reference-any-way-to-get-around-this)

**Edit2:** For clarity, if you're wondering why I'm using `make_shared()`, in my actual code the `sharedFoo` variable is a class member of a third class (independent of `Foobar` and `Baz`).

Comment: I can't test atm, but shouldn't that be;
std::shared_ptr<Foobar> sharedFoo = std::make_shared<Foobar>(myBaz);

Comment: Ah! That did the trick... apparently `make_shared()` calls the constructor of the templated type for you, so I shouldn't have been passing in a `new`'ed object. Thanks! Say that again as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Done, after being able to test it myself :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be;

```
std::shared_ptr<Foobar> sharedFoo = std::make_shared<Foobar>(myBaz);
```

...since make_shared constructs the actual object for you by running the constructor.