# Correct use of shared_ptr and make_shared in exercise from Stroustrup's PPP book Chapter 12

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am working an exercise from Chapter 12 of Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.

The graphics interface library in this chapter, `Simple_window.h` and `Graph.h` provides a simple wrapper around FLTK. Source code is available at http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/

To attach a `Shape` to a `Window`, users must provide a reference to a `Shape` object, which must exist for the lifetime of the `Window`. The relevant member function has the following signature:

```
void Graph_lib::Window::attach(Shape& s);
```

Referencing the comments in [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c) I would like to make use of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` to ensure that the allocated `Rectangle` objects (which derive from `Shape`) match the lifetime of the `Simple_window` object (which derives from `Window`).

First solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"

/*
Exercise 4 from Chapter 12
Programming Principles and Practice using C++, page 434

Draw a checkers board: 8-by-8 alternating white and red squares.
*/

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace Graph_lib;
    using Graph_lib::Rectangle;

    try {
        Simple_window win(Point(20,20),400,300,"Exercise 12.4");
        vector<shared_ptr<Shape>> shapes;

        const auto width = 20;
        const auto height = 20;

        for (auto row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (auto col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                auto x = col * width;
                auto y = row * height;
                shared_ptr<Rectangle> r(new Rectangle(Point(x,y),width,height));
                shapes.push_back(r);
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    r->set_fill_color((col % 2 == 0) ? Color::white : Color::red);
                } else {
                    r->set_fill_color((col % 2 == 1) ? Color::white : Color::red);
                }
                win.attach(*r);
            }
        }
        win.wait_for_button();
    }
    catch(exception &e) {
        cerr << "Exception occured: " << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Unknown exception occured" << endl;
        return 2;
    }
}
```

To make the use of the smart pointer less explicit I extended `Simple_window` with a user-defined member function which pushes the smart pointers into the vector before passing the references along to `Simple_window::attach(Shape&)`:

```
struct Shared_simple_window : Simple_window {
    Shared_simple_window(Point xy, int w, int h, const std::string& title )
        : Simple_window(xy, w, h, title) { }

    void attach(std::shared_ptr<Graph_lib::Shape>&& s)
        { shared_shapes.push_back(s); Simple_window::attach(*s.get()); }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Graph_lib::Shape>> shared_shapes;

};
```

The code in the try block now becomes

```
Shared_simple_window win(Point(20,20),400,300,"Exercise 12.4");

const auto width = 20;
const auto height = 20;

for (auto row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (auto col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        auto x = col * width;
        auto y = row * height;
        shared_ptr<Rectangle> r(new Rectangle(Point(x,y),width,height));
        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            r->set_fill_color((col % 2 == 0) ? Color::white : Color::red);
        } else {
            r->set_fill_color((col % 2 == 1) ? Color::white : Color::red);
        }
        win.attach(r);
    }
}
win.wait_for_button();
```

This works, but my question is, how can I make use of `make_shared` in this example rather than `new`? I tried replacing the `shared_ptr` declaration with the following

```
auto r = make_shared<Rectangle>(Rectangle(Point(x,y),width,height));
```

but I get an error `use of deleted function Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(Graph_lib::Rectangle&&)`, probably because `Rectangle` is not designed to be moved. Should I extend `Rectangle` in order for it to work?

Comment: How about `auto r = make_shared<Rectangle>(Point(x,y),width,height);` instead?

Comment: @Nick Thanks, now I feel foolish but in a good way. I tried different syntactical variations but the simplest one you provided turns out to be correct. Do you mind posting as an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: Similar Q and A also in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789636/errors-in-stdmake-shared-when-trying-to-make-shared-ptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try passing the same arguments you would pass to the constructor to `make_shared` like this:

```
auto r = make_shared<Rectangle>(Point(x,y),width,height);
```

Comment: I like this syntax over the version in my question because I can avoid typing `new` and also avoid typing `Rectangle` twice