# how to overcome make_shared constness

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm faced with a problem, and can't decide what the correct solution is.

Here is the code example for illustration:

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class TestClass{
    public:
        int a;
        TestClass(int& a,int b){};
    private:
        TestClass();
        TestClass(const TestClass& rhs);
};

int main(){
    int c=4;
    boost::shared_ptr<TestClass> ptr;

//NOTE:two step initialization of shared ptr    

//     ptr=boost::make_shared<TestClass>(c,c);// <--- Here is the problem
    ptr=boost::shared_ptr<TestClass>(new TestClass(c,c));

}
```

The problem is I can't create a shared_ptr instance because of make_shared  gets and passes down arguments to TestClass constructor as `const A1&, const A2&,...` as documented:

```
template<typename T, typename Arg1, typename Arg2 >
    shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Arg1 const & arg1, Arg2 const & arg2 );
```

I can trick it with `boost::shared(new ...)` or rewrite the constructor for `const` references, but that doesn't seem like the right solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost make\_shared takes in a const reference. Any way to get around this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373896/boost-make-shared-takes-in-a-const-reference-any-way-to-get-around-this)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `boost::ref` to wrap the argument up, ie:

```
ptr = boost::make_shared< TestClass >( boost::ref( c ), c );
```

Comment: So much thank you! I will learn by hart that peace of boost doc:)